# Downloading XLSX file with Drive API v3

Tags: c#, excel, google-drive-api, console-application

I'm using the following method to download Google Doc and Google Sheet files- these are working fine.

```
public static MemoryStream DownloadFile(Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading file '{0}'", file.Name);
        string mimeType = null;
        switch (file.MimeType)
        {
            case MIMETYPE_GOOGLE_SHEET:
                mimeType = "text/csv";
                break;
            case MIMETYPE_GOOGLE_DOC:
                mimeType = "text/plain";
                break;
        }

        MemoryStream stream = null;
        if (mimeType == null)
        {
            // Unsupported extension
            Program.WriteColoredText($"The MimeType {file.MimeType} is currently unsupported.", ConsoleColor.Red);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            stream = new MemoryStream();
            var request = GetExportRequest(file.Id, mimeType);
            request.Download(stream);
        }
        return stream;
    }
```

Google Sheets can be downloaded as "text/csv" without issue. I've uploaded an XLSX file to Drive and attempted to download that file by adding the mimetype to the switch statement:

```
switch (file.MimeType)
        {
            case MIMETYPE_EXCEL_SHEET: //application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
            case MIMETYPE_GOOGLE_SHEET:
                mimeType = "text/csv";
                break;
            case MIMETYPE_GOOGLE_DOC:
                mimeType = "text/plain";
                break;
        }
```

But the `request.Download(stream)` call returns a stream with length 0 and no exceptions. Passing the actual mimetype "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" to `GetExportRequest()` has the same result.

Some searches on the web show that Excel files should be handled differently, but I wasn't able to find any definitive answer. Any ideas?